# Php query over wordpress db doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I try to query the wordpress database from a standalone php file named test.php and located on the root folder of the wp installation folder, but the query return nothing to be displayed, the var dump show nothing, what i do wrong and how to test if the hosting support mysqli?(credentials has been removed from db connection)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vxbQ.png)

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'passwd', 'dbname');

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
$result = $mysqli->query("select meta_value from wpde_postmeta where meta_key = '_product_attributes' and post_id = '41'") ;
    echo $result;
  var_dump($result);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: So post_id 41 exists I assume? Had to ask, sometimes it is that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the data fetch part:

```
// Just below $result = $mysqli->query("...") ;

while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
    // Do something with $obj->meta_value
}
```